# We need to kill the [domain-registrar] tag

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

The tag, [domain-registrar](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/domain-registrar) is pretty useless and out of topic, it needs to be killed.

Comment: Just don't go removing the tag right now if they're off topic. Just vote or flag to close first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the tag is used and all its questions are off topic, we can just close and delete them.

The tag clean up process will then take out the tag from use if it's no longer on any undeleted questions.